# Connecting to google cloud SQL Error using Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, flask-login

I'm totally beginner for use flask and Google Cloud SQL. I want to make Login and Registration in my app using Flask-Login and Flask-SQLAlchemy.
But I can't connect to google cloud SQL using Flask-SQLAlchemy, this is my code.

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
'mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@/{db_name}'
'?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{connection_name}').format(
    user=db_user, password=db_password,
    database=db_name, connection_name=connection_name)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
```

I just got this error :
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 2] No such file or directory)")

But, when I try to make a connection using SQLAlchemy with this code, the connection is succeeded :

```
query_string = dict({"unix_socket": "/cloudsql/{}".format(connection_name)})
driver_name = 'mysql+pymysql'

db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
    drivername=driver_name,
    username=db_user,
    password=db_password,
    database=db_name, 
    query=query_string),
pool_size=5,
max_overflow=2,
pool_timeout=30,
pool_recycle=1800)
```

But when I tried to change the code like this :

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = db
```

then, I got this error: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'drivername'.

Any suggestion for this problem? any advice, might be very helpful for me, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This line right here actually assigns the "engine" object to your URI config:

```py
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = db
```

You can use the url object to create a URI instead:

```py
uri = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
    drivername=driver_name,
    username=db_user,
    password=db_password,
    database=db_name, 
    query=query_string)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = uri.render_as_string(hide_password=false)
```

You can compare the URI to the one you created and see where they differ. It's likely there is a typo, or that some value is [escaped incorrectly](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#database-urls).

Comment: Thank you @kurtisvg for your answer, but I got a new error: "Instance of 'URL' has no 'render_as_string' member"

Comment: @HikmahDwiyantiNasir - Perhaps make sure you are on a recent version - it's listed in the SQLAlchemy documentation here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL.render_as_string